# Create user & group if it does not exist using Ansible

Tags: authentication, ansible, createuser, create-guid

I have a customized requirement.

1. Check if user `tomuser` belongs to group `tomuser` & exists no matter what the uid, gid is; then simply do nothing i.e. we are good.
2. if group `tomuser` does not exist create group `tomuser` with `gid` `1900`.
3. if user `tomuser` does not exist create user `tomuser` with `gid` `1900` and assign in the the group `tomuser`.
4. Finally if `uid, gid` `1900` is already in use while creating user and group then prefer `uid,gid` as `2020` and if that too is in use then any random unique number is fine for both.

Below, is something I could think off which I understand is not the ideal solution; but i also end-up with issues

playbook below:

---

```
- name: Check tomuser user in passwd file
  tags: always
  ignore_errors: yes
  block:

    - group:
        name: tomuser
        gid: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "1900"
        - "2020"
      register: groupcreated            
      when: "tomuser" in groups

    - debug:
        msg: "GROUP tomuser does not exists or is empty"
      when: 'tomuser' not in groups and not groups['tomuser']

    - debug:
        msg: "GROUP tomuser does not exists"
      when: 'tomuser' not in groups

    - debug:
        msg: "GROUP tomuser is empty"
      when: not groups['tomuser']


    - raw: "cat /etc/passwd |grep -i tomuser"
      register: tomusercheck
```

Output:

```
TASK [Check tomcat USER on server] *************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/patch/patch.yml:81
fatal: [10.9.9.44]: FAILED! => {
    "reason": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  did not find expected key\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/patch/checktomuser.yml': line 11, column 30, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n            gid: '1900'\n          when: \"tomuser\" in groups\n                             ^ here\nThis one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started\nwith a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended\nwith the same kind of quote. For instance:\n\n    when: \"ok\" in result.stdout\n\nCould be written as:\n\n   when: '\"ok\" in result.stdout'\n\nOr equivalently:\n\n   when: \"'ok' in result.stdout\"\n"
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Your first when clause cannot be parsed => `when: '"tomuser" in groups'`. You'll get a similar problem for the next ones you also have to fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. Should be idempotent as well.

```yaml
---
- hosts: my_host
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: determine available groups
      getent:
        database: group

    - name: determine available users
      getent:
        database: passwd

    - name: set group with gid 1900 when not available
      group:
        name: tomuser
        gid: 1900
      when:
        - "'tomuser' not in ansible_facts.getent_group"
        - "'1900' not in item.value"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_group | dict2items }}"

    - name: set group with gid 2020 when not available
      group:
        name: tomuser
        gid: 2020
      when:
        - "'tomuser' not in ansible_facts.getent_group"
        - "'2020' not in item.value"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_group | dict2items }}"

    - name: create random number
      set_fact:
        random_num: "{{ range(1500, 2000) | random(seed=item) }}"
      run_once: yes
      with_items:
        - string

    - name: set group with random gid when 2020 already in use
      group:
        name: tomuser
        gid: "{{ random_num }}"
      when:
        - "'tomuser' not in ansible_facts.getent_group"
        - "'2020' in item.value"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_group | dict2items }}"

    - name: set fact when tomuser exists
      set_fact:
        user_exists: true
      when: '"tomuser" in item.key'
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items }}"

    - name: set fact when tomuser does not exists
      set_fact:
        user_exists: false
      when: '"tomuser" not in item.key'
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items }}"

    - name: set user with uid 1900, and group tomuser when not available
      user:
        name: tomuser
        uid: 1900
        group: tomuser
      when:
        - not user_exists
        - "'1900' not in item.value[1]"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items }}"

    - name: set user with uid 2020, and group tomuser when not available
      user:
        name: tomuser
        uid: 2020
        group: tomuser
      when:
        - not user_exists
        - "'2020' not in item.value[1]"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items }}"

    - name: set user with random uid, and group tomuser when not available
      user:
        name: tomuser
        uid: "{{ random_num }}"
        group: tomuser
      when:
        - not user_exists
        - "'2020' in item.value[1]"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You first problem is this: `when: "tomuser" in groups`
The `groups` variable contains host groups in your inventory, not user groups on the host.

Second the `group` module will add/modify groups. So if the group does not exist, your code will add it with `gid` 1900 and then change the `gid` of that group to 2020. So after your loop finishes, your group will always have `gid` 2020.

To update the groups of the user, you can use the `user` module.
To check if a user or group exists, you can use the `getent` module.

Check the documentation of the [group module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_module.html), [user module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html) and [getent module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/getent_module.html).